# Network sharing problem

Tags: networking

I have done a search on this message board with no answer forthcoming. I recently upgraded to OS 6 from 5. I am running elementary on a 2013 MacBookPro as the sole operating system. In OS 5 I used to stream films from my iMac(OSX High Sierra) on the home network. I am unable to do this in the upgrade. My laptop is not visible on the network from my iMac. The "Entire Network" icon when pressed shows "Windows Network" and I am unable to switch it to AFP. I have installed Samba and Network Manager with no resolution to this problem. I have rebooted the laptop and this did not resolve the issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have an update on this. My iMac, the computer I want to stream from, is connected via ethernet. When I switch it to Wifi I can then connect this to my elementary OS laptop and browse files. However, when I attempt to watch a film the laptop freezes. Any ideas on a fix for this?

Comment: A further update to this problem as I have now solved it. I had to log into my router and add my laptop into the LAN settings.